# Cannot click button in table using Selenium in Python 3.7

Tags: python, selenium

The image below shows the button inside the table that I want to click.

[The button that I'm trying to click via Selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTP38.png)

The problem is that, in the website's source code, there are no code listed in the  elements:

[Click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbA5h.png)

This is in contrast with what is shown in the Inspect Element tab.

I tried the following codes, but they did not work:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("table[@id='overviewTable']//tr//following::th[@class='']")
link.click()

link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("sorting_asc")
link.click()
```

Assuming that I imported the Selenium files correctly since there are no error messages regarding that, where did I go wrong?

This is the [link](http://covid19tracker-laguna.mcl-ccis.net/index.php) to the website.

Comment: Can you post the website link?

Comment: I got to see this xpath: `//th[@class='sorting_asc']` try it.

Comment: @JenilDave, it didn't work. I used the try-and-except clause, and it returned me a string "Element not found" (this is my error handling).

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='overviewTable']//tr/th[contains(text(),'CITY')]"]
link.click
```

and perform click action for sorting

1. First click for asc sorting
2. second for desc sorting